# MarkerWithLabel with DOM Elements - mouseOver event

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put a little div in the labelContent of my Markers when the 'mouseover' event is triggered.

But the problem is that everytime the mouse moves (inside that div) the mouseout event is triggered.. Without DOM Elements it works fine, but if I put some divs, img etc the problem starts happening.

I'm using the basic.html from markerWithLabel page, with some modifications

```js
function initMap() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
  var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var text = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<img src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logos/careers-logo.png?v=4daa70d5b71e">AAAAAAAAAA<br><br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB<p> ALFA </p> BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB<br><br>BBBBB';
  var html = '<div id="" style="margin-top:2px">' +
    '<div>' +
    '<div width="285">' +

    '<div width="90" height="80" align="center" style="vertical-align: top">' +
    '<div style="display:inline-block;margin-top: 12px;">' +
    '<img src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logos/careers-logo.png?v=4daa70d5b71e" width="80" height="52">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div width="185" align="left" style="color:#FFF; font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">' +
    '<div style="display:inline-block;height:80px;margin-top: 2px;overflow:hidden" title="TITULO DO MARCADOR" alt="ALT DO MARCADOR">' +
    '<div style="font-family: arial,tahoma;line-height: 14px;color:white"><strong>TITULO DO MARCADOR</strong><br> 6 quartos<br>Valor: 15000000 <br>Area: 120 m2</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';


  var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: homeLatLng,
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    pane: "overlayMouseTarget",
    map: map,
    labelContent: "$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA425K",
    labelNovo: text,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {
      opacity: 0.75
    }
  });

  markers.push(marker1);

  var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.475, -123.84),
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,
    pane: "overlayMouseTarget",
    labelContent: "$395K",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {
      opacity: 1.0
    }
  });
  markers.push(marker2);


  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers /*, mcOptions fix javascript error */ );

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseover", function(e) {
    console.log('mouseover');
    this.set('labelContent', this.labelNovo);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseout", function(e) {
    console.log('mouseout');
    this.set('labelContent', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz')
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseover", function(e) {
    this.set("labelContent", html)
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseout", function(e) {
    this.set("labelContent", 'OUTOUTOUTOTU')
  });


  window.map = map;

}
```

```css
.labels {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 500px !important;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>MarkerWithLabel Example</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
  <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="initMap()">

  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</body>

</html>
```